# QFutureWatcher not calling connected slot

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

I have the following code which implements `QtConcurrent::run()` with `QFutureWatcher` to start the `fetch()` function which runs a shell process. Upon completion, I want to call the `writeDesc` function, but it never gets called.

```
void MyClass::on_fetchButton_clicked()
{
    QFuture<void> fetcher;
    QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(writeDesc()));
    fetcher = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::fetch);
    watcher.setFuture(fetcher);
}

void MyClass::fetch()
{
    [...]
    qDebug()<<"Thread done";
}

void MyClass::writeDesc()
{
    qDebug()<<"Slot called";
    [...]
}
```

`fetch()` works fine but the program shows only the debug message `Thread done` and not `Slot called`. Why isn't `writeDesc` being called?

Comment: Reminder: questions with problems caused by an automatic variable getting destroyed at the end of a function are subject to closure. They are in the "simple typo" category. OTOH, it's true that Qt could offer a qWarning in destructors of some classes that are especially prone to such misuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the watcher object is destroyed when leaving the `MyClass::on_fetchButton_clicked()` method. A destroyed object can not emit something. Try to allocate and connect the watcher in the constructor of your class. Don't forget to destroy in the destructor.